# Potree/three.js cancel measurement

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm using Potree (https://github.com/potree/potree) for the visualization of a massive point cloud.

I'm starting an area-measurement (Potree.MeasuringTool) which is normally stopped/accepted by a right-click. I'd like to want it to stop at the click of a button. Can someone point me in the right direction which function to call? I'm not that into javascript. Also, a simulation of a right-button click will be accepted by me, although it's maybe not the prettiest solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried every possible solution/function saying something about cancellation of a measurement. Found out this was just what I needed in potree.js;

```
viewer.dispatchEvent({
    type: "cancel_insertions"
    });
```

Of course, this is only applicable if the measurement is still active.

Answer (score 1):

without event :

```
viewer.measuringTool.sceneMeasurement.remove(viewer.measuringTool.sceneMeasurement.children[viewer.measuringTool.sceneMeasurement.children.length - 1]);
```